# Mouse arrow symbol

Tags: symbols

Is there any predefined symbol in LaTeX for the standard mouse symbol? Something like

[image]

Thank you for all your comments.

Comment: If you need actual [mice](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/333100/14593)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't find it in http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-letter.pdf and was also unsuccessul with Detexify (http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), so I guess it is not there as a predefined symbol. But you can just download this symbol (e.g., from http://findicons.com/search/cursor) and use it with `\includegraphics`.

Answer (score 3):

I worked out a pointer for you. You may visit following:
https://www.sharelatex.com/project/549873ebe6f6925860adcc5a

Open latex2.tex file and then compile.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mpoint}
\begin{document}
This is \mpoint .
\end{document}
```

Here, I have called a sty file. Which is very simple. May be upgraded more.

```
\RequirePackage{graphicx,graphics}
\newcommand{\mpoint}{\includegraphics[width=0.016\textwidth]{point}}
```

and two image files - point.pdf and point.eps

Final out put is as 
[image]

Hope this will help you.

Comment: you can install three files point.pdf/eps and mpoint.sty as package.

Answer (score 2):

You can also add one with a simple Ti*k*Z drawing.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85} % LuaTeX fix for standalone
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4, line join=round]
    \draw [rotate=20.9245] (-1.5pt, 0pt) -- ++(up:5pt) -- ++(-5pt, -2pt) -- ++(6.5pt, 17pt)
                      -- ++(6.5pt, -17pt) -- ++(-5pt, 2pt) -- ++(down:5pt) -- cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You can use the resulting pdf with `\includegraphics{...}`
[image]

Or use the code directly in your text:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85} % LuaTeX fix for standalone
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\mouse}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4, line join=round]
    \draw [rotate=20.9245] (-1.5pt, 0pt) -- ++(up:5pt) -- ++(-5pt, -2pt) -- ++(6.5pt, 17pt)
                      -- ++(6.5pt, -17pt) -- ++(-5pt, 2pt) -- ++(down:5pt) -- cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
  Click me \raisebox{-5pt}{\mouse} OK
\end{document}
```

Which gives:
[image]

The rotation angle is calculated from the `++(6.5pt, 17pt)` using
[image: formula]

Answer (score 2):

[Fontawesome](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome) provides a symbol named *mouse-pointer*. Load the packet with

```
\usepackage{fontawesome}
```

and access the symbol with

```
\faMousePointer
```

The symbol looks like:
[image]